# Android Enable TLSv1.2 in OKHttp

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

i am using OKHttp for my project. i want to enable TLSv1.2 for my service call. can any body tell me how to enable it.

Comment: how does it work for you?
Please tell me I can't ask question on stackoverflow

Comment: This solution fixed my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45853669/3448003

Answer (score 13):

See OkHttp’s [HTTPS documentation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS).

```
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS) 
  .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
  .cipherSuites( 
     CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
     CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
     CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
  .build();
OkHttpClient client = ... 
client.setConnectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));
```

Comment: as the documentation says - this would only work on android 5.0 or higher

Comment: It doesn't even work on Android 5.0.  I get SSL HandshakeException.

Comment: @ShanXeeshi explain how it doesn’t work? It’s likely a problem that your webserver isn’t configured for TLS 1.2.

Comment: now what should i do for below lolipop because its not working ? 
I am getting this exception **UnknownServiceException Unable to find acceptable protocols. isFallback=false, modes=[ TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, ....], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_2], supportsTlsExtensions=true)], supported protocols=[SSLv3, TLSv1]**

Comment: Hi @jesse-wilson, 
I've tried - unfortunately it doesn't work for me

        `ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                    .allEnabledCipherSuites()
                    .allEnabledTlsVersions()
                    .build();`

I still have the error:
`Retrofit: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

Comment: tested on android devices: 4.4.2; 6.0.1; 7.0

Comment: Thanks, that's the simplest way to get it work! Tested on Android 7.0

Comment: the same as @IgorGanapolsky, I got  `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO`

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know OKHttp does not include own SSL/TLS libraries, therefore it just uses the standard SSLSocket provided by Android.

What TLS versions are supported (and enabled) depends on the used Android version.
On some phones TLS 1.2 is supported but not enabled by default (as far as I remember this affects phones with Android 4.1/4.2/4.4). In such cases you could enable it by implementing a custom wrapper SSLSocketFactory that uses internally the default SSLSocketFactory and calls `setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLS1.2"})` on every Socket that is created.

On device with Google Services installed the preferred way to enable TLS 1.2 on old Android 4.x device is using [ProviderInstaller](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider).

Comment: Thanks for this sugestion. I`ve combined it with https://stackoverflow.com/a/38962842/5251437. If the `ProviderInstaller` fails (or exception is thrown) I`m trying to use custom SSLSoketFactory that sets enabled protocols...

Answer (score 6):

Check My Code!!Working perfect!

```
private void checkTls() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        try {
            ProviderInstaller.installIfNeededAsync(this, new ProviderInstaller.ProviderInstallListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProviderInstalled() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderInstallFailed(int i, Intent intent) {
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            finish();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use this before you call web service. Just need to call once in your app

Comment: This solution will not work for everyone.  The ProviderInstaller class comes from Google Play Services, and Google Play Services is not available on every Android device.  Most notably in China, where GPS is disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my solution is very similar to Ken's (except in Java). I found it [here](http://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/) although had to make a couple of small changes to get it to work. Hopefully this works '*out of the box*' for others.

```
public class TLSSocketFactoryCompat extends SSLSocketFactory {

private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

public TLSSocketFactoryCompat() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, null, null);
    internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
}

public TLSSocketFactoryCompat(TrustManager[] tm) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, tm, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket());
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
}

private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
    if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
        //Create list of supported protocols
        ArrayList<String> supportedProtocols = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String protocol : ((SSLSocket)socket).getEnabledProtocols()) {

            //Log.d("TLSSocketFactory", "Supported protocol:" + protocol);
            //Only add TLS protocols (don't want ot support older SSL versions)
            if (protocol.toUpperCase().contains("TLS")) {
                supportedProtocols.add(protocol);
            }
        }
        //Force add TLSv1.1 and 1.2 if not already added
        if (!supportedProtocols.contains("TLSv1.1")) {
            supportedProtocols.add("TLSv1.1");
        }
        if (!supportedProtocols.contains("TLSv1.2")) {
            supportedProtocols.add("TLSv1.2");
        }

        String[] protocolArray = supportedProtocols.toArray(new String[supportedProtocols.size()]);
        /*for (int i = 0; i < protocolArray.length; i++) {
            Log.d("TLSSocketFactory", "protocolArray[" + i + "]" + protocolArray[i]);
        }*/

        //enable protocols in our list
        ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(protocolArray);
    }
    return socket;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    //Add Custom SSL Socket Factory which adds TLS 1.1 and 1.2 support for Android 4.1-4.4
    try {
        httpClient.setSslSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactoryCompat());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I had high hopes for this but I see `Enabling TLS 1.2
Enabling TLS 1.2
Enabling TLS 1.2
Enabling TLS 1.2
Enabling TLS 1.2
Enabling TLS 1.2
Enabling TLS 1.2
Enabling TLS 1.2
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0x5ff7f518: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1256 0x5fe90e28:0x00000003)
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:568)`

Comment: at least it tries enableTLSOnSocket() 8 times, over the course of a few seconds, before giving up.

Comment: Someone Somewhere, I'm not sure the error you're getting is actually related (could be a cert issue) but it reminded me that I updated this class to ensure that the list of supported protocols were only added to. I think before it may have left only TLS 1.1 and 1.2 enabled. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I found out today that the issue I was seeing was due to firmware issues with the device. The app can do no magic if the underlying firmware is just broken.

Comment: how can I implement for httpclient?? I mean to how to set setSslSocketFactory?

Comment: Why am I getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to extract the trust manager on Platform, sslSocketFactory is class`

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as the answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249630/android-enable-tlsv1-2-in-okhttp#29252730) but I feel like a code sample would be useful for anyone else who lands here and isn't up to speed on navigating the java ssl landscape.

What ultimately ended up working for me was based on the issue reported here: https://github.com/mattleibow/square-bindings/issues/1
from this gist https://gist.github.com/mattleibow/c8abfa323db094b820cc

Note these code samples are in C# / Xamarin but can be translated to java fairly easily.

```
internal class CompleteSSLSocketFactory : SSLSocketFactory
{
    private readonly SSLSocketFactory innerFactory;

    public CompleteSSLSocketFactory (SSLSocketFactory innerFactory)
    {
        this.innerFactory = innerFactory;
    }

    public override string[] GetDefaultCipherSuites ()
    {
        return innerFactory.GetDefaultCipherSuites ();
    }

    public override string[] GetSupportedCipherSuites ()
    {
        return innerFactory.GetSupportedCipherSuites ();
    }

    public override Socket CreateSocket ()
    {
        return MakeSocketSafe (innerFactory.CreateSocket ());
    }

    public override Socket CreateSocket (Socket s, string host, int port, bool autoClose)
    {
        return MakeSocketSafe (innerFactory.CreateSocket (s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    public override Socket CreateSocket (string host, int port)
    {
        return MakeSocketSafe (innerFactory.CreateSocket (host, port));
    }

    public override Socket CreateSocket (string host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort)
    {
        return MakeSocketSafe (innerFactory.CreateSocket (host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    public override Socket CreateSocket (InetAddress host, int port)
    {
        return MakeSocketSafe (innerFactory.CreateSocket (host, port));
    }

    public override Socket CreateSocket (InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort)
    {
        return MakeSocketSafe (innerFactory.CreateSocket (address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private Socket MakeSocketSafe (Socket socket)
    {
        var sslSocket = socket as SSLSocket;
        if (sslSocket != null) {
            // enable all supported protocols for this socket
            sslSocket.SetEnabledProtocols (sslSocket.GetSupportedProtocols ());
            sslSocket.SetEnabledCipherSuites (sslSocket.GetSupportedCipherSuites ());
        }
        return socket;
    }
}
```

And then calling it like:

```
// this.client is an OkHttpClient
if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop) {
    this.client.SetSslSocketFactory(new CompleteSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.DefaultSSLSocketFactory));
}
```

This worked for me, tested on API 19.