# "Connection closed by peer" error occurs in Android 7.0 Nougat while connecting to SHA256 CA installed Windows 2003 Server SP2 through HTTPS

Tags: android, https, sha256, sslhandshakeexception, android-7.0-nougat

My app communicates with server interface (classic ASP) through HTTPS.
It has been workd very well in prior version of Android 7.0 Nougat. (until 6.0)
But, Connection closed by peer Error occurs in Android 7.0 phone and AVD(Android virtual device).
Server is Windows 2003 Server SP2 (SSL Certificate was updated from SHA1 to SHA256 in Jul 23th, 2016), HTTPS, Classic ASP
Server's SSL certificate installation check status of GeoTrust is like below
(cryptoreport.geotrust.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp)
[GeoTrust check status screen shot of my Server's certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Ta4.png)
(Protocols not enabled : TLS1.1, TLS1.2)

In my opinion, Android 7.0 fails SSL handshaking with Windows 2003 Server of TLS1.0(only TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 can support successful handshaking with SHA256 certificate?)
Is this right?
And I just found this hot fix : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968730
Is this can be a solution?

How could I fix this problem

Comment: Problem is for Server side. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968730 hotfix can be a solution.

Comment: So your problem is only happening with Windows servers?

Comment: problem is on client side ) here is solution for `Volley`, but can be applied also for `okHttp` or `HttpsUrlConnection` [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40198170/5147817)

Comment: Did you solve this problem. Could you share the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we changed server to Win 2008...;;
That's the only solution in my opinion.