# React Native fetch() throws 'Network request failed' on Android 7, but works fine on Android 6

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I have found ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144938/react-native-android-fetch-for-https-returns-network-request-failed)) that fetch request ends successfuly on Android SDK Platform 23 (Android 6), but on Android SDK Platform 24 (Android 7) I have error 'Network request failed':

```
try {
   let res = await fetch('https://pricesea.ru/api/auth/login', {
     method: 'POST',
     credentials: 'include',
     headers: new Headers({'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}),
     body: `username=${this.state.username}&password=${this.state.password}`
   });

   if (res.ok) {
     ...
   }
} catch (e) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Network request failed
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (fetch.js:441)
at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:546)
at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:381)
at XMLHttpRequest.js:485
at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:260)
at MessageQueue.js:101
at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:228)
at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:100)
```

I am using RN 0.46.3.

What could be the reason of that?

**EDIT:** I have tested API versions from 22 to 26, problem is only on API 24 (Android 7.0). On other API versions request ends successful.

**EDIT 2:** Github RN issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15100

Answer (score 2):

That's a bug on Android 7.0, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133437/sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failed-on-android-n-7-0). 
Workaround proposed by Vicky Chijwani:

> Configure your server to use the elliptic curve prime256v1. For
>   example, in Nginx 1.10 you do this by setting ssl_ecdh_curve
>   prime256v1;

Comment: This worked perfectly, despite sacrifying a little on security..  Since Nginx 1.11.0 and OpenSSL 1.0.2 one can specify multiple ciphers `ssl_ecdh_curve prime256v1:secp384r1;` - see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_ecdh_curve