# React native fetch() fails when making request to a HTTPS server for only Android 7.0

Tags: android, laravel, ssl, react-native

Please I am kind of new to asking questions so bear with me.
I am currently working on a react native (0.56) project that communicates with a laravel API(https). So when I tested it on an android device (6.0 and 5.0) the request was successful but unfortunately testing it on android 7.0 keeps showing the same error `network request failed`. I have tried the solution that was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170365/react-native-fetch-throws-network-request-failed-on-android-7-but-works-fin) but still no changes. Please any suggestion would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133437/sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failed-on-android-n-7-0), there is a bug in 7.0 version of Android. Which solution did you tried ?

Comment: i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133437/sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failed-on-android-n-7-0)

Comment: Do you know the IP adress of your server ? If so, try to use it instead of localhost.

Comment: I am not using locahost, the server has been deployed and i have also tried to access it from its IP and it isn't working