# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed while loading the image in Glide

Tags: android, android-glide, android-7.0-nougat, sslhandshakeexception

I am using **Glide** library for showing the image but in **android 7.0** the image are not showing, "`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed`" exception are coming.

Please give me some best solution for these exception. I have go through many sites but right answer not given in any site.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42047877/3983054

Comment: It could also happen if your web api has untrusted SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have valid SSL configuration [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html).

If whole chain is proper then you can trust particular certificate at runtime.

Ref : [Glide intercept network](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-module-example-accepting-self-signed-https-certificates) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39883606/3746306).

Answer (score 0):

For me it got resolved by using

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

in the manifest.