# Letsencrypt does not work on Android

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have a digitalocean server (ubuntu 16.4 nginx) + serverpilot
I installed letsencrypt Following the site tutorial: 
https: //www.robertwent.com/blog/using-letsencrypt-serverpilot/

Everything worked out, the result was this: https://testelcon2.tk

The problem:
The site works with ssl installed on all desktop browsers
However, in mobile android browsers it does not work.
The error message I receive is a red padlock and the message:
NET: ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

I tested other sites I found on the internet to see if the problem was only with my site, and they all work normally in my mobile browser (crome, safari and native browser)

I am 4 days trying to solve this problem, but without success. What could be happening? What did I do wrong?
Can someone check for me?
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=testelcon2.tk
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://testelcon2.tk

Comment: Probablybetter asking on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There ia a known issue in Android 7.0 with HTTPS connections regarding elliptic curves. If the problem occours only on Android 7.0 devices (the bug only exists in this version) it's probably it.

The easiest workaround is to configure the server to use `prime256v1` ellipitic curve. If you use nginx just set

```
ssl_ecdh_curve prime256v1;
```

I know your error message doesn't suggest anything to do with ellipitic curves but I was stuck with this problem in React Native getting a missleading error message and only changing the elliptic curve setting in my server solved it so maybe it can help you.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42047877/1084033) answare explains the issue much better than myself.

Comment: Ok, good luck. Hope it helps someone to not lose as much time as I did with this :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's more likely to be a `ssl_ciphers` server-side settings problem.

Change your `ssl_ciphers` settings on nginx to the one recommended by [openHab](https://www.openhab.org/docs/installation/security.html) :

```
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!CBC:!EDH:!kEDH:!PSK:!SRP:!kECDH;
```

Don't forget to reload (`systemctl reload nginx`) and now all problematic android devices should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed older versions of Android have problem with Let's Encrypt certificates, in my case they evidently do not trust `Internet Security Research Group` and require presence of other authority(ies) in the chain. Use `openssl s_client -connect [domain]:443 -prexit` to inspect the chain in case the problem is for older versions of android and it works only with certain sites that use Let's encrypt. Example output for a working domain I've tested:

```
CONNECTED(00000184)
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = www.seznam.cz
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = www.seznam.cz
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   i:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
 2 s:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
```

Both use Let's Encrypt, but my domain does not have `Digital Signature Trust`.

The best way of inspecting a domain wrt. various devices is

> https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html