# SSL Handshake Failure on Oreo

Tags: android, ssl

I am trying to interact with a server using a self signed certificate.

It works fine for Nougat but has an exception for Oreo:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:444)
```

Based off Android O's [changelog](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#networking-all), it does seem like things have changed in regards to insecure protocol fallbacks. I'd just like to make sure that my trust manager isn't the issue:

```
public static OkHttpClient getClient() {
    try {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                    }
                }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);

        // Allow our hostname
        builder.hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> {
            return hostname.equals(API_HOST_NAME);
        });
        builder.addInterceptor(new MyCustomInterceptor());
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            builder.addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC));
            builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor());
        }
        return builder.build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The server's configurations are based off of [this example](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html).

Is there anything visibly wrong with my client, or is this perhaps an issue on the server?

Comment: Same exception here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately

Comment: Any luck fixing it ? or any relevant solution ?

Comment: Still no unfortunately. It also seems like this issue is happening on Samsung devices with Nougat. I'm still waiting on more logs so I can get a better idea of the issue

Comment: We fixed the issue on our end. I've referenced the stack overflow post that helped us below. Note that this ended up not being an Android O bug as presumed

Answer (score 0):

After more testing, it seemed like it was working on Oreo, and was namely an issue with Android 7.0

The solution to our problem is found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133437/sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failed-on-android-n-7-0) stack overflow, which references [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37122132) Android bug.

To summarize, the issue had to do with Android 7.0 supporting only one elliptic curve.