# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate

in my app get this type of error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
              at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:441)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:472)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:65)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:145)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
              at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)
              at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
              at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
              at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
          Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xf363eb00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
          error:100c5410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0xeebb4ce0:0x00000001)
          error:100c009f:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_hello:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:771 0xea03b7f7:0x00000000)
              at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
              at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:353)
            ... 19 more
          javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
              at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:441)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:472)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:65)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:145)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:860)
              at cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
              at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:146)
              at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:177)
              at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:106)
              at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
          Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake terminated: ssl=0xf363eb00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
          error:100c5410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:972 0xeebb4ce0:0x00000001)
          error:100c009f:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_hello:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_clnt.c:771 0xea03b7f7:0x00000000)
              at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
              at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:353)
            ... 19 more
```

Comment: Can you please add the code producing that exception? We need to be able to reproduce your issue. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It may not support the protocol of TLSV1.3 . Maybe you need see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133437/sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failed-on-android-n-7-0)

Comment: This is way too broad. It might be a problem in your code, in the age of your software stack, in the server .... There is no way to reproduce it based on the few information. Please have a look at [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException%3A+Handshake+failed") if they answer your problem. If not at least get the detail needed to  successfully answer a question from the existing one and fix your question accordingly.