# _firebaseMessaging.getToken() not working with some devices

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

```
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      assert(token != null);
      deviceToken = token;
    });
```

Here is my function to get firebase token, which is working fine for most of android devices, having issue with old android devices. Here I am sharing detail of that device. Does anyone know what is the exact issue?

Redmi Note 4
Android version : 7.0 NRD90M
MIUI Version : MIUI Global 11.0.2

Comment: Please share logs while  calling this method  firebaseMessaging.getToken() for that specified device.

Comment: Actually I don't have that device so not able to debug. I just got information about this scenario.

Comment: Able to generate token on Android 6 device  : Samsung galaxy j7

Comment: Ok, Let me check with some other workflow. Thank you.

Comment: Able to generate on android 7.1.1 as well Samsung Tab E

Comment: It may happen if you are storing that token to your server through api and and that api may not working in android 6 and android 7 platform due to ssl stuff

Comment: Ok, Is there any way that I can confirm this scenario?

Comment: You can create Emulator for android 7 or andoid 6  and check that api working or not ?
You have to create device with google play services. So, you will get fcm working

Comment: Yes, It is issue with api, which is not working with android 7 platform. Its not about _firebaseMessaging.getToken(). Thank you @HardikMehta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is issue with api, which is not working with android 7 platform. Its not about _firebaseMessaging.getToken()

Comment: Yes You got it now.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133437/sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failed-on-android-n-7-0 for api error issues