# okHTTP Unable to find acceptable protocols(android)

Tags: android, ssl, https

Sorry for my english. I try using libruary OKhttp, and i use **https** for post reqest. Now i have error, when i try post my example, this is error:

```
java.net.UnknownServiceException: Unable to find acceptable protocols. isFallback=false, modes=[ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_2], supportsTlsExtensions=true)], supported protocols=[SSLv3, TLSv1]
```

I try fix it, but i cant do this. I dont know what i have this error

And bellow my code:

```
public class PostOKhttp extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String...ulr) {
            Response response = null;
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                    .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                    .cipherSuites(
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
                            CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA)
                    .build();
            client.setConnectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));

            RequestBody postForm = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                    .add("name", "name")
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ulr[0])
                    .addHeader("id", "--")
                    .addHeader("key", "--")
                    .post(postForm)
                    .build();

            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                Log.e("post", response.body().string());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", e.toString());
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
```

**UDP:**

Use **CertificatePinner**

i add this code

```
String link = "example.net";
CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                    .add(link, "sha1/DmxUShsZuNiqPQsX2Oi9uv2sCnw=")
                    .add(link, "sha1/SXxoaOSEzPC6BgGmxAt/EAcsajw=")
                    .add(link, "sha1/blhOM3W9V/bVQhsWAcLYwPU6n24=")
                    .add(link, "sha1/T5x9IXmcrQ7YuQxXnxoCmeeQ84c=")
                    .build();

            client.setCertificatePinner(certificatePinner);
```

Now i have this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Comment: So does your backend support TLS1.2 with at least one of the cipher suites you've listed?

Comment: @laalto if i use TLS_1_0 or TLS_1_1 i have same error

Comment: The ` supported protocols=[SSLv3, TLSv1]` part of the output suggests your backend only supports ancient TLS1.0 and obsolete SSL3 and none of the ciphersuites you've declared.

Comment: @laalto if i do like this `.tlsVersions(TlsVersion.SSL_3_0)` i have error `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found`

Comment: If you're using self-signed certs, use a CertificatePinner to pin them. But do consider upgrading your server to modern TLS instead of reverting to less secure old protocols and ciphers.

Comment: @laalto thanks for answer. I update me qestion, now i add `CertificatePinner ` and i have error `SSLHandshakeException`

Answer (score 13):

Actually the problem is **TLSv1.1** and **TLSv1.2** not enabled on **Android <5** by default and to connect using these latest secure protocol we must have to enable in Android <5 devices.

Because by default android device pick the highest supported protocol to establish the connection but the highest/ newest secure protocol (eg. TLSV1.1 or TLSV1.2) are not enable by default (only enabled are SSLV3.0 or TLSV1.0).

**Enabling the TLSV1.1 and TLSV1.2 in android < 5**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

/**
 * @author Bajrang Hudda
 */

    public class MyTLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

        private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

        public MyTLSSocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, null, null);
            internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
            return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
            return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket());
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
            return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
            return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
            return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
        }

        private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
            if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
                ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
            }
            return socket;
        }
    }
```

And now add it in your Okhttpclient -

```
 protected static OkHttpClient getHttpClient(long timeout){

        String hostname = Constants.HOST_NAME_DEBUG;
        CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                .add(hostname, "sha1/mBN/TTGneHe2Hq0yFG+SRt5nMZQ=")
                .add(hostname, "sha1/6CgvsAgBlX3PYiYRGedC0NZw7ys=")
                .build();

        //specifying the specs; this is impotent otherwise android <5 won't work 
        //And do note to include the android < 5 supported specs.
        ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_1, TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                .cipherSuites(
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
                        CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
                .build();

        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.setCertificatePinner(certificatePinner);
        okHttpClient.setConnectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));
        try
        {
            // enabling the tlsv1.1 and tlsv.2
            okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(new MyTLSSocketFactory()); 
        } catch (KeyManagementException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return okHttpClient;
    }
```

And now finally add it in your retrofit -

```
 RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Constants.API_URL)
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler())
                .setClient(getHttpClient())
                .setRequestInterceptor(new SecureHeaderInterceptor(null))
                .build();
```

That's it, Happy Coding :-)

Comment: I tried your code but I got error `The method setCertificatePinner(CertificatePinner) is undefined for the type OkHttpClient`, why?

Comment: You might not be using latest version of okhttp, see this -https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html

Comment: Here is in my build.gradle file `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'`, is it older?

Comment: Okay, show me the code where you are trying to call this method.

Comment: Are you using only com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient class or any other import? because this is the right one.

Comment: I use`import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;`, is this not correct?

Comment: Basically there are two types of imports available

1). import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;

2). import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

and you should use the 1st one only.

Comment: but build.gradle compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0' cannot import `com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient`...

Comment: first remove import okhttp3.OkHttpClient from import section and the try again to import  import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient this only

Comment: I tried `import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;`, The result is `The import com.squareup cannot be resolved`

Comment: Did you put in gradle file - implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0' - *latest version* of these libraries.

Comment: I am using `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'`, is this not OK?

Comment: I got it! that is `builder.certificatePinner(certificatePinner);` in okhttp3, you used okhttp2.

Comment: Cool, happy coding @mikezang

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `ProviderInstaller` to check and install if needed TLS support. Use something like this on your entry `Activity` and it should do the trick. Check more info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html)

```
protected void checkTls() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        try {
            ProviderInstaller.installIfNeededAsync(this, new ProviderInstaller.ProviderInstallListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProviderInstalled() {
                    SSLContext sslContext = null;
                    try {
                        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
                        sslContext.init(null, null, null);
                        SSLEngine engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderInstallFailed(int i, Intent intent) {
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem