# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed on Android 5.0.0 when SSLv2 and SSlv3 are disabled (TLS only) (and greater)

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, retrofit

This is my first post and I'm going to try to do my best to be as clear as possible (sorry for my english).

Here is my trouble, I'm using retrofit:1.9.0 and okhttp:2.7.5 to perform API call. Everything was fine until my server provider disable SLLv2 and SSLv3 cause of sercurity trouble (Drown fail found on first March).

Now I check the information about my provider and he allows only TLSv1 with cypher (TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA  No FS) from https://www.ssllabs.com/.

Ok so this is all the tests I've done and results:

**[UPDATE PROBLEM SOLVED]**

Find a way to solve this problem in my second answer.

**UPDATE**
It seems that the problems comes from the google API version. When I test on API 18 everything is working fine. When it's on Android greather or equal to 5.0.0 it fails.

### **First test**

**Conf. recap:**

- compileSdkVersion 23
- buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
- minSdkVersion 18
- targetSdkVersion 21
- retrofit:1.9.0
- okhttp:2.7.5
- Android version > 5.0.0 (but it's the same on every device...)

**Rest Client (LoginRestClient):**

```
public class LoginRestClient
{
    private static final String BASE_URL = "";
    private LoginApiService apiService;

    public LoginRestClient()
    {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'")
                .create();

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(ApiIntentService.getHostAddress())
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                .setClient(new OkClient(ApiIntentService.getConnectionHttpClient()))
                .build();

        apiService = restAdapter.create(LoginApiService.class);
    }

    public LoginApiService getApiService() {
        return apiService;
    }
}
```

**Function to create client OkHttpClient getConnectionHttpClient()**

```
public static OkHttpClient getConnectionHttpClient()
{
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



        ConnectionSpec specs = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS)
                .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_0)
                .cipherSuites(CipherSuite.TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA)
                .build();

        okHttpClient.setConnectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(specs));

    return okHttpClient;
}
```

**Result in public void failure(RetrofitError error) from custom CallBack**

*java.net.UnknownServiceException: Unable to find acceptable protocols. isFallback=false, modes=[ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_0], supportsTlsExtensions=true)], supported protocols=[SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]*

### **Second test**

I've made a custom SSLSocketFactory to disable SSLv3 and force TLS:

```
/**
 * @author fkrauthan
 */
public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

    public TLSSocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, null, null);
        internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
        if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
            ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1"});
        }
        return socket;
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
public static OkHttpClient getConnectionHttpClient()
    {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        try {
            TLSSocketFactory tlsSocketFactory = new TLSSocketFactory();
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(tlsSocketFactory);
            okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(tlsSocketFactory);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 return okHttpClient;
}
```

**Result in public void failure(RetrofitError error) from custom CallBack**

*javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7f87885280: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:770 0x7f87c2fdf0:0x00000000)*

If anyone can help me It will be very cool. All my apps are down and I'm fighting against this problem since yesterday morning to restore my services. I'm removing my hair one by one...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27126109/1617737

Comment: This solution fixed my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45853669/3448003

Comment: I found the solution and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58067717/8551420).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

Hi everyone after fighting during 3 days and nights here is the final solution.
So thanks to the solution here:

[How to disable SSLv3 in android for HttpsUrlConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649389/how-to-disable-sslv3-in-android-for-httpsurlconnection)

and this library: https://guardianproject.info/code/netcipher

It permits to provide to Android a better way to work with cypher and TLS in case where SSLv2 and SSlv3 are disabled.

First create this class NoSSLv3SocketFactory.java and couple this with a CypherUrl connection by creating a constructor like this

```
public NoSSLv3SocketFactory(URL sourceUrl) throws IOException {
        this.delegate = NetCipher.getHttpsURLConnection(sourceUrl).getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
    }
```

**NoSSLv3SocketFactory.java (complete code)**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedListener;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

import info.guardianproject.netcipher.NetCipher;


public class NoSSLv3SocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory{
    private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

    public NoSSLv3SocketFactory(URL sourceUrl) throws IOException {
        this.delegate = NetCipher.getHttpsURLConnection(sourceUrl).getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
    }

    public NoSSLv3SocketFactory() {
        this.delegate = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
    }

    public NoSSLv3SocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    private Socket makeSocketSafe(Socket socket) {
        if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
            socket = new NoSSLv3SSLSocket((SSLSocket) socket);
        }
        return socket;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private class NoSSLv3SSLSocket extends DelegateSSLSocket {

        private NoSSLv3SSLSocket(SSLSocket delegate) {
            super(delegate);

        }

        @Override
        public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols) {
            if (protocols != null && protocols.length == 1 && "SSLv3".equals(protocols[0])) {

                List<String> enabledProtocols = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(delegate.getEnabledProtocols()));
                if (enabledProtocols.size() > 1) {
                    enabledProtocols.remove("SSLv3");
                    System.out.println("Removed SSLv3 from enabled protocols");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("SSL stuck with protocol available for " + String.valueOf(enabledProtocols));
                }
                protocols = enabledProtocols.toArray(new String[enabledProtocols.size()]);
            }

            super.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
        }
    }

    public class DelegateSSLSocket extends SSLSocket {

        protected final SSLSocket delegate;

        DelegateSSLSocket(SSLSocket delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
            return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getEnabledCipherSuites() {
            return delegate.getEnabledCipherSuites();
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnabledCipherSuites(String[] suites) {
            delegate.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getSupportedProtocols() {
            return delegate.getSupportedProtocols();
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getEnabledProtocols() {
            return delegate.getEnabledProtocols();
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols) {
            delegate.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
        }

        @Override
        public SSLSession getSession() {
            return delegate.getSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void addHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener listener) {
            delegate.addHandshakeCompletedListener(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener listener) {
            delegate.removeHandshakeCompletedListener(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void startHandshake() throws IOException {
            delegate.startHandshake();
        }

        @Override
        public void setUseClientMode(boolean mode) {
            delegate.setUseClientMode(mode);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getUseClientMode() {
            return delegate.getUseClientMode();
        }

        @Override
        public void setNeedClientAuth(boolean need) {
            delegate.setNeedClientAuth(need);
        }

        @Override
        public void setWantClientAuth(boolean want) {
            delegate.setWantClientAuth(want);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getNeedClientAuth() {
            return delegate.getNeedClientAuth();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getWantClientAuth() {
            return delegate.getWantClientAuth();
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnableSessionCreation(boolean flag) {
            delegate.setEnableSessionCreation(flag);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getEnableSessionCreation() {
            return delegate.getEnableSessionCreation();
        }

        @Override
        public void bind(SocketAddress localAddr) throws IOException {
            delegate.bind(localAddr);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
            delegate.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void connect(SocketAddress remoteAddr) throws IOException {
            delegate.connect(remoteAddr);
        }

        @Override
        public void connect(SocketAddress remoteAddr, int timeout) throws IOException {
            delegate.connect(remoteAddr, timeout);
        }

        @Override
        public SocketChannel getChannel() {
            return delegate.getChannel();
        }

        @Override
        public InetAddress getInetAddress() {
            return delegate.getInetAddress();
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return delegate.getInputStream();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getKeepAlive() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getKeepAlive();
        }

        @Override
        public InetAddress getLocalAddress() {
            return delegate.getLocalAddress();
        }

        @Override
        public int getLocalPort() {
            return delegate.getLocalPort();
        }

        @Override
        public SocketAddress getLocalSocketAddress() {
            return delegate.getLocalSocketAddress();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getOOBInline() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getOOBInline();
        }

        @Override
        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            return delegate.getOutputStream();
        }

        @Override
        public int getPort() {
            return delegate.getPort();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized int getReceiveBufferSize() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getReceiveBufferSize();
        }

        @Override
        public SocketAddress getRemoteSocketAddress() {
            return delegate.getRemoteSocketAddress();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getReuseAddress() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getReuseAddress();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized int getSendBufferSize() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getSendBufferSize();
        }

        @Override
        public int getSoLinger() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getSoLinger();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized int getSoTimeout() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getSoTimeout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getTcpNoDelay() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getTcpNoDelay();
        }

        @Override
        public int getTrafficClass() throws SocketException {
            return delegate.getTrafficClass();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isBound() {
            return delegate.isBound();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isClosed() {
            return delegate.isClosed();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isConnected() {
            return delegate.isConnected();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isInputShutdown() {
            return delegate.isInputShutdown();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isOutputShutdown() {
            return delegate.isOutputShutdown();
        }

        @Override
        public void sendUrgentData(int value) throws IOException {
            delegate.sendUrgentData(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void setKeepAlive(boolean keepAlive) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setKeepAlive(keepAlive);
        }

        @Override
        public void setOOBInline(boolean oobinline) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setOOBInline(oobinline);
        }

        @Override
        public void setPerformancePreferences(int connectionTime, int latency, int bandwidth) {
            delegate.setPerformancePreferences(connectionTime, latency, bandwidth);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void setReceiveBufferSize(int size) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setReceiveBufferSize(size);
        }

        @Override
        public void setReuseAddress(boolean reuse) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setReuseAddress(reuse);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void setSendBufferSize(int size) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setSendBufferSize(size);
        }

        @Override
        public void setSoLinger(boolean on, int timeout) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setSoLinger(on, timeout);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void setSoTimeout(int timeout) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setSoTimeout(timeout);
        }

        @Override
        public void setTcpNoDelay(boolean on) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setTcpNoDelay(on);
        }

        @Override
        public void setTrafficClass(int value) throws SocketException {
            delegate.setTrafficClass(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void shutdownInput() throws IOException {
            delegate.shutdownInput();
        }

        @Override
        public void shutdownOutput() throws IOException {
            delegate.shutdownOutput();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return delegate.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return delegate.equals(o);
        }
    }
}
```

and now (in my case with retrofit) just use it like this:

**So first,** Add a static method (or as you want create it on use) to make a okHttpClient with our previously created NoSSlv3Factory.java class.

```
public static OkClient createClient(int readTimeout, TimeUnit readTimeoutUnit, int connectTimeout, TimeUnit connectTimeoutUnit)
{
    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(readTimeout, readTimeoutUnit);
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout, connectTimeoutUnit);

    try {
        URL url = new URL(ApiIntentService.getHostAddress());
        SSLSocketFactory NoSSLv3Factory = new NoSSLv3SocketFactory(url);
        okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(NoSSLv3Factory);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new OkClient(okHttpClient);

}
```

**Then**, in my case when you create your RestAdapter just make it like this, and don't forget to set you client.

```
public class LoginRestClient
{
    private static final String BASE_URL = "";
    private LoginApiService apiService;

    public LoginRestClient()
    {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'")
                .create();

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setEndpoint(ApiIntentService.getHostAddress())
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                .setClient(ApiIntentService.createClient(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .build();

        apiService = restAdapter.create(LoginApiService.class);
    }

    public LoginApiService getApiService() {
        return apiService;
    }
}
```

With this it should be working.
I hope it will be usefull for someone else.

Comment: Hi kevzzz can you help me out with my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946350/okhttp-android-websocket-and-jetty-server-connection-with-ssl

Comment: A very similar solution worked for me before. I took it from here:
https://medium.com/@krisnavneet/how-to-solve-sslhandshakeexception-in-android-ssl23-get-server-hello-tlsv1-alert-protocol-13b457c724ef
For an unknown reason it doesn't seem to work anymore.

However, the solution of Taz seems to be working now.

Answer (score 14):

I found the solution here in [this link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-OkHttp#enabling-tls-v1-2-on-older-devices).

You just have to place below code in your Android application class. And that is enough. Don't need to do any changes in your Retrofit settings. It saved my day.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    try {
      // Google Play will install latest OpenSSL 
      ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
      SSLContext sslContext;
      sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
      sslContext.init(null, null, null);
      sslContext.createSSLEngine();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
        | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will be of help. Thank you.

Comment: Great, it helped me! Do you know what's the difference with the solution from kevzzz? It worked for me several months ago, but now it doesn't anymore. Some change in the Android framework or so? Anyway, I'm happy to have found your solution instead!

Comment: This saved me after searching for days why some phone just wont connect

Answer (score 4):

If you are using OkHttpClient use

```
OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
client.connectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS));
```

And the do client.build() when setting your client.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have included https:// instead of sending http:// to your server