# How to solve black screen in Android WebView?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I'm setting up a url `https://turnbackhoax.id/` inside a `WebView`. But the `WebView` is just showing a blank page. I have tried to set other URLs and those work. I've learned and searched for a similar problem but nothing changed.

Following is my `WebView` code:

```
public class LaporPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webV;
    Activity activity;
    private ProgressDialog progDailog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lapor_page);

        activity = this;

        progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading","Please wait...", true);
        progDailog.setCancelable(false);

        webV = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);

        webV.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webV.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webV.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webV.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webV.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webV.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                progDailog.show();
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                progDailog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        webV.loadUrl("https://turnbackhoax.id/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795589/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failed-on-android-5-0-0-when-sslv

Comment: any url with http is working?

Comment: In your case, your URL is getting SSL Handshake error, check this link for more info - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795589/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-handshake-failed-on-android-5-0-0-when-sslv

Comment: @PradipVadher many url

Comment: @Shane but i just make a simple webView, not use retrofit etc

Comment: Is that site responsive to mobile UI ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the URL, it is throwing an SSL handshake error in the web view. Although it's not a good practice to ignore the SSL error but this will solve your problem

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    }


});
```

Comment: WHAAAAA.. THANK YOU SO MUCH . I'M SO GLAD THANK YOU THANK YOU IT'S WORK

Comment: where do i need to add this code?

Comment: @Binnikumari in onCreate

Answer (score 2):

Its simple and Exact Solution is to **enable the DomStorage** & set **setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true**

```
    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);        

    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);    // this 
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);  //and this
```

It will solve the problem.

Enjoy it.

Comment: Where to keep this code in project?

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission under your Manifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Use this:

```
 wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        wv.setInitialScale(1);      //webview page matches the screen size.
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);    //loads online website when no internet connection.
        wv.loadUrl("https://prajwalwaingankar.wixsite.com/nivala");
```

Comment: i have set that permission before and still not worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to use override onReceivedSslError

Try this

```
webV.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            progDailog.show();
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                                       SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            progDailog.dismiss();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

create file called `network_security_config.xml`,

```
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <debug-overrides>
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</base-config>
<domain-config>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.example.com</domain>
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="@raw/mycert" />
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</domain-config>
```

In Manifest,

```
<application ..... 
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

</application>
```

and add your SSL if required

Answer (score 0):

To properly handle SSL certificate validation and avoid application rejection from Google according to new Security Policy, Change your code to invoke **SslErrorHandler.proceed()** whenever the certificate presented by the server meets your expectations, and invoke SslErrorHandler.cancel()

```
webV.setWebViewClient(new  WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
                webV!!.loadUrl(url)
                return true
            }

            override fun onReceivedSslError(
                view: WebView, handler: SslErrorHandler,
                error: SslError
            ) {
                handler.proceed()
            }
        });
```