# Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]

Tags: jboss

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]
at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:357) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:313) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:304) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.onServerHello(ServerHello.java:946) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$ServerHelloConsumer.consume(ServerHello.java:873) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:376) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:479) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:457) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:200) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:154) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1290) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:401) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_301]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1824)
... 44 more

Comment: Kindly share if you've solved the same question

Comment: KIndly provide more information.
- code that you are trying to run.
- what you want to achieve

Comment: Have you had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718383/how-to-change-client-tls-preferences-in-java ?